# How to handle audio files dynamically in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a Next js project setup with an api route handler that is supposed to download an audio file from a different service based on the users parameters. I stored the downloaded files in a folder in my root directory like /downloadedAudio. Once the audio has been downloaded, I want to play it.

On localhost, the audio file is downloaded and saved by the api but giving my audio player the path of the newly generated audio file does not work and I get an `GET http://localhost:3000/downloadedAudio/[audio file name].mp3 404 (Not Found)`

Is it even possible to dynamically get the downloaded audio and play it or do I have to use a different storage bucket if the files aren't static.

Code for the route api

```js
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server"

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  var sdk = require("SoundApiSdk")

  const { searchParams } = new URL(request.url)

  const soundName = searchParams.get("soundName")

 
  try {
    let audioFileStore = `./synthesizedAudio/${soundName}.mp3`
    
    await sdk.downloadSound(soundName,audioFileStore)
     
      
      return NextResponse.json(
        { msg: "Sound downloaded" },
        {
          status: 200,
        }
      )
    
  } catch (error: any) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: error.message }, { status: 500 })
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Code I'm using to play the sound on the client

```js
const dounloadSound = async (soundName: string) => {
    await fetch(`/api/sound?soundName=${soundName}`)
    let downloadedSound = new Audio(`/downloadedAudio/${soundName}.mp3`)  //  causing the error
    downloadedSound.playbackRate = 0.9
    downloadedSound.play()
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You should use external blob storage in this case (Vercel blob, S3, etc.)